# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I'm unable to run django mongo engine properly.

My database entry in settings.py is

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': 'local',
}
}
```

and my pip freeze result is

```
Django==1.8.2
django-mongodb-engine==0.5.2
djangotoolbox==1.6.2
pymongo==3.0.2
```

error while running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

is

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseFeatures
```

Any suggestions how to solve this.

Comment: Take a look at [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/)

Comment: @ajaysingh, how to solve this problem? i am facing  same issue

Comment: @jignasha `django-norel` is not supported in latest versions of django. This library is deprecated.

Comment: @ajaysingh,so What is alternative to use mongoDB with Django? how to solve this problem?

Comment: For my specific use case, I moved to flask.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using djongo and face this error when you call make migrations do this:

Open terminal and install pytz (pip install pytz)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You need `django-nonrel` installed as well, as per the [documentation](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html).

Comment: trying this : pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5 but nothing is happening after this. Any alternatives to install django-nonrel?

Answer (score 1):

But, the main drawback is `django-nonrel` works only if you use `Python2.x`, it cannot work with `Python3.x`

Comment: This sounds more like a comment and not as an answer to this question. If I am wrong, please edit your answer to clearly demonstrate how this answers the question. Otherwise, please leave it as a comment once you earn enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling 'Pymongo' and install it as 'pip install pymongo' as compared to installing it via an ide

Comment: Hi, how did you fix the issue "React app with Django error 'string indices must be integers'"? You seem to have deleted the question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the same problem with my **pipenv** activated. Later, I figured out **djongo** was not installed in my **pipenv**. I just installed it. It's been working fine now.

```
pipenv install djongo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. If you plan to work with `Django 1.7.x, 1.8.x`, a lib that works just fine is:
`django-mongoengine v0.2.1`

In later versions (`pip install django-mongoengine`) it comes forced the install of Django 2.x (which you can still cancel by adding `--no-deps`) but still, less hassle if force the django-mongoengine package version by:
`pip install git+https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine@v0.2.1

The `requirements.txt` file remains something like this:

```
Django==1.7.11
-e git+https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine@4ea7168faf9b6f67a5c9e8e82690b4310aca0ff0#egg=django_mongoengine-v0.2.1
djangotoolbox==1.8.0
mongoengine==0.13.0
pymongo==2.8
pyserial==3.1.1
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

The good of of [django-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) is that mongoengine easily allows you to [access pymongo](http://docs.mongoengine.org/upgrade.html?highlight=get%20collection#python-and-pymongo) methods:

```
class Post(Document):
    #fields    

collection = Post._get_collection()
collection.update({}, {"$set": {"newfield": 1}}, multi=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the django utils.py file does not recognize that django is an available backend. To solve this error, please follow these steps:

1. Go to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages` and find the django folder.
2. Now cut and paste the django folder in the
   `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site -packages\django\db\backends` directory.
3. Now you might be getting the error cannot import six from django.utils. For resolving that go to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\django\operations.py` file and replace the line `from django.utils import six , datetime` to `from django.utils import datetime` and beneath that just write `import six`.
4. Now in the settings.py file of your django project add the lines

   ```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.djongo',
       'NAME': 'admin',
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of pymongo and djongo are not compatible,
This works :

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-rest-framework = "*"
social-auth-app-django = "*"
social-auth-app-django-mongoengine = "*"
django-ses = "*"
djongo = "==1.3.6"
python-dotenv = "*"
djoser = "*"
pymongo = "==3.12.3"
pytz = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```