# connect mongodb with djongo (Django)

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

i try connect to mongodb with `djongo`
after reading [githup page of djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) and [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NoSqlSupport) 
find same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527086/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-django-mongodb-engine-isnt-an-av) but no answer as well
change `setting.py` like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'namename',
    }
}
```

after run `python manage.py makemigrate` i get this error:

djongo' isn't an available database backend try using "django.db.backend.XXX" where XXX is  one of : "mysql" , "oracle" , "postgresql" , "sqlite3"

mongodb version = 3.4

python version = 3.6.3

djogo == 1.2.38

Comment: The error clear, isn't?

Comment: yes it is clear , djongo conver mongo query to sql or somthing like this , i must work

Comment: Did you install djongo? What does `pip freeze | grep djongo` output?

Comment: yes i do, djongo==1.2.38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should downgrade Django version to 2.2.8 and reinstall the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongoengine to connect django with mongodb and add above line in your settings.py file.

```
import mongoengine
import pymongo

HOST = 'localhost:27017'

mongoengine.connect(
    db='dbname',
    host=HOST,
    read_preference=pymongo.ReadPreference.PRIMARY_PREFERRED
)
```

Comment: and how aboat `DATABASES` in setting.py ? i should change it ?

Comment: You can leave it blank. I have used on server and I gave blank. But if you are trying on local host give sqlite3 which comes by default.

Answer (score 1):

**2022**: It seems `djongo` doesn't work with the latest versions (4.X) of `django` and `pymongo`, because I solved the issue with:

```
django==3.2.14
pymongo[srv]==3.12.3
```

Answer (score 1):

python version also matters: for me python 3.8.14 works. Tested with the following dependencies.

```
Python==3.8.14
Django==3.2.15
djongo==1.3.6
Mongo==3.6
pymongo==3.12.3
```

I think latest version of djongo with Django 3.x.x works perfect but pymongo, Mongo, and Python must be kept same.

Answer (score 0):

First install djongo

```
pip install djongo
```

then next makemigration and migrate

Answer (score 0):

> i install djongo it works for me with latest version of django
> my django version is 3.2.7
> mython version is 3.8
> `pip install djongo`  will install the latest version,
> in my case the command installed of `djongo 1.3.6` by default
>
> and change the DB in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
       }
    }
```